# OSX Hid: List of possible usage pages, where can I find it ?(i.e. kHIDUsage_GD_GamePad etc.)

Tags: c, macos, keyboard, hid

I am developing some Hid Managment classes on osx and after googling for quite some time now I still don't seem to find any complete list of the possible osx hid usage pages (i.e kHIDUsage_GD_GamePad, kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard  ...) can anyone provide a link?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This header file should list all these enum constants:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-315.7.16/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDUsageTables.h

Comment: Do you know it there is allready something for multitouch devices even though it does not look like it depending on the .h you provided? WTF: kHIDUsage_Sim_MagicCarpetSimulationDevice :)

Comment: @moka: Check the Digitizer page. You can get more information on what are usages and usage pages in http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/. Also, there's no restriction on what page a multitouch device will use. It all depends on the vendor. Use the "USB Prober" to get the exact info for that device.